# latexmk cleanup after complile and do not clean synctex files

Tags: latexmk

I am trying to make latexmk cleanup after compiling

But I have 2 problems:

1. `latexmk -pdf -c xx.tex` only does the cleaning but not compiling
2. `latexmk -c` will delete `synctex` files which I do not want to delete, I do not find an exception settings

How to deal with these?

Comment: If you delete all the auxiliary files after compiling, there's not a big gain from using latexmk in the first place. The biggest advantage of latexmk is that it only runs the tools needed, but if you remove the necessary input files, it has to run them all the time.

Comment: .... this will cause exactly the problems described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673072/why-does-latexmk-compile-my-latex-file-twice Make your life easier and **don't** routinely clean up the files

Comment: The `-c` option to latexmk causes it to delete intermediate generated files **instead** of compiling the document.  If you want to do a compilation and then a clean-up, you need to do the operations separately.  E.g., on a Unix-like system, run `latexmk -pdf xx.tex; latexmk -c xx.tex`.  The clean up operation does preserve `synctex` files as well as the pdf files.